# floated divs still in vertical line, not horizontal as they should be

Tags: css, html, css-float, alignment

On [my site](http://frshstudio.com/about/), near the bottom there is a "FREE ACCESS" section. Ideally, I'd like to have the freedom image on the left, the signup form in the middle, and the success image on the right. The width of the 3 elements is right at 840px total in a 960px container, so I don't think that's an issue. For this, I'm using:

```
        .signup {
    border-top: 1px solid #333333;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 280px;
}

.signup p {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.signup p span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.signup #mc-embedded-subscribe {
    background: #0fddaf;
}

.signup .freedom {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}

.signup .success {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

[And the HTML.](http://pastebin.com/Y1H8XBkk)

As you can see, something isn't working quite right and I've been looking at this for so long I'm afraid I'm missing something simple. Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

Take the width from `.signup`, float `.form` left, and give it 280px width;
or take the width from `.signup`, and give `.form` an extra class `.freedom`. (`<div class=' freedom form'>` - quite rebellious, eh?)

*Ta-da!!*

## Advice

1. Learn CSS before you work with it, it will save you time and headaches in the future;
2. ???
3. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

Give a width to the element you are floating, then it should behave predictably.

Comment: I've given each div a width of `280px`, no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have not looked at the container element, but you would NOT want a width on that.

Answer (score 0):

Float .freedom, .form, and .success all left. Then, remove the width from .signup.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you've got an absolute size for each of the divisions, you should be able to get what you want by floating them all to the left and giving them the sizes you want to get them where you want them to be.

You'll also need to add `overflow:auto` to the `.signup` container div so your floated content stays within it.

Comment: All area sized properly, and floated left. No changes noticed.

Comment: The layout should end up looking like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7A4d) - do you have padding or margins which are  making the divs larger and stopping them from fitting side by side in the container?

Answer (score 0):

You want freedom image on left, sign up in the middle and success image on right. s???
To get this first float the freedom image and sing up on the left by taking the width apparently. then float the success image on right.

In the above css please remove the clear: both; and clear all floats at the end of the all floats by using the another div like
div.clear{clear:both}

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. However, after making the edits to the code I noticed no changes on the site. Ideas? (I've changed the code in my original question to reflect your edits.)